# How to expand a shape by a factor of 2 in every direction?

Tags: geometry, area

So, I'm reading the book, and the author says about some "Area rules". Here's one of them I didn't understand.

“If you expand a shape by a factor of 2 in every direction, then its area multiplies by 4.”

What does it mean? I can't imagine what's gonna happen with a shape(for example, triangle, rectangle, pentagon or circle) if I do it.
I don't understand this part "every direction". Does it mean 4 directions? Up, down, right, left?
And why is it multiplied by 4?

Can somebody explain it to me? (or even draw a picture). I'll be really thankful!

Comment: Something like: if $S$ is a plane set then the expanded set is $\{(2x,2y): (x,y)\in S\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Expand a shape by a factor of $2$ in every direction" means that you make the shape larger in such a way that the distance between any two points doubles. A square with side lengths $1$ would become a square with side lengths $2$, and a circle with radius $5$ would become a circle with radius $10$.

This is opposed to, for instance, just expanding by a factor of $2$ horizontally, which stretches things, so that a square with side lengths $1$ becomes a rectangle with width $2$ and height $1$, and a circle with radius $5$ (and therefore diameter $10$) becomes an ellipse with width $20$ and height $10$.

If you look at what happens to the areas of these shapes when you expand by a factor of $2$ in each direction, you see that the area goes form $1\times 1 = 1$ to $2\cdot 2 = 4$ for the square and $\pi\times 5^2 = 25\pi$ to $\pi\times 10^2 = 100\pi$ for the circle, and we see that they have both increased by a factor of $4$. There is nothing special about circles or squares here; this increase by a factor of $4$ when distances double happens to  *any* shape (and is, in some contexts, the definition of two-dimensional). If we expand by a factor of $3$ in all directions, then you can check, for instance with the square and the circle, that areas increase by a factor of $9$. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your shape is given as set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Then its twofold expansion is the set $2S:=\{2s\vert s\in S\}$. For example if $S$ is a disk with radius $r$, then $2S$ is a disk with radius $2r$, if $S$ is a rectangle with sidelengths $a$ and $b$, then $2S$ will be a rectangle with sidelengths $2a$ and $2b$ and so on, i.e. you are zooming into the picture.

The statement about areas then follows from the substitution rule. If $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, x\mapsto 2x$, then $DF_x=2I$, thus $\det(DF_x)=2^2=4$ and
$$
A(2S) = \int_{F(S)}d{y_1}d{y_2}=\int_S\vert \det DF_x\vert dx_1dx_2 = 4 \int_Sdx_1dx_2 = 4 A(S)
$$

Answer (score 1):

All directions means here in the directions of your base vectors. That is in the direction of the $x$- and $y$-axis. Think like this:

if you take a $1$ dimensional object, say a line segment with lenght $1$ unit then if you double the lenght of it you en up with a line segment of lenght $2$ units.

next if you build a square of with four of this $1$ unit long line segments you end up with a square having area $1=1^2$ area units, right? Now if you double all the one dimensional objects in this picture you en up with a square having side lenght $2$ units which has area $4=2^2$ area units.

next start again with the $1$ unit long line segment and build a cube. This cube has volume $1=1^3$ volume unit. Now if you double all the one dimensional objects in your picture you essentially build a cube with side lenght $2$ having volume $8=2^3$ volume units.

Try to draw this down and think about it.

Comment: Yeah, it becomes clearer when I draw it. Thanks. It really helped!

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The key words here are "in every direction".

To illustrate my point, imagine a line. Since it is $1$-dimensional, you only need to extend it by a factor of $2$ once. For a $2$-dimensional square, you now need to extend its **length** by a factor of $2$, and its **height** in every direction. Therefore, the area changes by a factor of $2^2$.

We can continue this pattern in $3$ dimensions as well. By extending its **length**, **width** and, **height** by a factor of $2$, the volume increases by a factor of $8$.

You can also do it this way as well:
Every 2D shape can be written in the form $cs^2$, where $s$ is the side length, and $c$ is an arbitrary constant depending on the shape. For example, for a square $c=1$, and an equilateral triangle has $c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

So if we increase the side by a factor of $2$ by letting $t = 2s$, then the area becomes $4cs^2$, which is $4$ times larger than $cs^2$.

Comment: I think this one is the easiest to understand!

Comment: @VitaliiPaprotskyi Thanks! I only wrote this answer because I felt that the other answer were too complicated and hard to understand as well!

Comment: yes, you're right! For example, the Jabo's answer is way too complicated for me :)